# Conditional tag only for front of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I've created the custom post type (CPT) called 'projects':

```
$post_type_args = array(
            //...
            'has_archive'          => true,
            'rewrite'              => array(
                // 'slug'       => '', // Defaults to $post_type key
                // 'with_front' => true, // Default true
                // 'feeds' => 'true', // Default has_archive value
                // 'pages' => true, // Default true
                // 'ep_mask' => EP_PERMALINK,
            ),
);

register_post_type( 'projects', $post_type_args );
```

And I would like the use a conditional tag **only for the front page** of the CPT.
In my case is the page with the slug `/projects`.

I can use `$_SERVER` array like this:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/projects/" ) { //... }
```

But is there something `like is_shop()` conditional tag in WooCommerce for this case?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

there is an `is_post_type_archive()` function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_post_type_archive/ that will tell you if you are on the https://example.com/projects/ page.

In your case you would need to use it like this

```
is_post_type_archive( "projects" );
```

since "projects" is your custom post type name.

Comment: Thanks it works.